# 5V USB for motorcycle using MC33063A

Tags: usb, dc-dc-converter

I'm trying to build an accessory power device for my motorcycle. At the moment I'm using the board from a ripped apart USB car charger for the 5 V part, but I'm trying to build a complete circuit.

I've reviewed [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/31066/17609), but I still can't work out what values I need to use for each component to get the output I want.

I'll be delivering anything between 11.2 V and 14 V into the circuit. I would like to get 5 V out at up to 1.5 A. Looking at [the datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/mc34063a.pdf) it says it will do 1.5 A out. However, when I try and use [an online calculator](http://www.bobtech.ro/tutoriale/componente-electronice/43-calculator-online-mc34063a-mc34063-step-down-step-up-inverter) it tells me that the switch peak for the circuit would be 3000 mA and that exceeds the 1500 mA max value. From what I can tell, this is because I'm trying to go from 12 V to 5 V.

Can I do what I'm trying to with the MC33063A or do I need to look at a different component to base the circuit around? If so, which should I be looking at?

For the record, the reason I want 1.5A out of the 5V circuit is that I want to be able to power / charge a GPS (TomTom Rider) and also a bluetooth USB dongle. I would also like the ability to charge a phone (iPhone 4 / 4S / Samsung S3) when not using the GPS and bluetooth dongle.

Comment: about samsung S3... beware the USB trick: S3 shorts D+ and D- ( data pins) to inform the phone that's charger, not a pc, connected. If you do not short these wires, the charging current will be below 100mA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The peak switch current and the average output current are two different things. For a switchmode regulator operating just at the brink between discontinuous mode and continuous mode, the peak switch current (peak coil current) is by definition going to be 2× the average output current. This means that the chip you've selected is only going to be able to handle an average output current of 750 mA.

Comment: Can you recommend a chip that would be able to do 1.5A average output ?

Comment: I have been happy with the TI [LM25005](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm25005.pdf) on several projects. It can handle output currents up to 2.5A.